# ActiveAdmin index - sort or filter on count column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a requirement to sort/filter a column in an ActiveAdmin view.  The column is the count of a sub-object.  Specifically, the model looks like:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_many :things
...
```

The ActiveAdmin page needs to have a column for this, which I have like this:

```
column 'Thing Count', :sortable => 'Thing Count' do |location|
  location.things.length
end
```

However, the sorting does not actually work, and I have not been able to figure out a way to make filtering work either.  I've tried several variations on:

```
:filter 'Thing Count'
```

with no success.  Has anyone ever successfully got ActiveAdmin to sort or filter on a count column of sub objects?  If so how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin can only have filters on database columns.

You can do the following:

1. Make a [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) column on the `belongs_to` side / Thing model.
2. Make a filter for that column `filter :things_count`
3. Recalculate the counter for each Thing.

Example:

```
def up
  add_column :projects, :tasks_count, :integer, :default => 0

  Project.reset_column_information
  Project.find(:all).each do |p|
    Project.update_counters p.id, :tasks_count => p.tasks.length
  end
end

def down
  remove_column :projects, :tasks_count
end
```

Comment: No dice.  I did this:  ` belongs_to :location, counter_cache: true` and then added the column and filter `things_count` to the page but the values are all blank and the filter does not appear.

Comment: Ah I see.  I think its working now.  So basically, I needed to seed the counter for all existing items, then the model change will keep it up to date, correct?  Looks good so far, thanks!

Comment: Yes, after a first counter seed, the model keep everything up to date

Answer (score 0):

```
class Location
  has_many :things

  def self.all_things
    joins(:things).select("locations.id as loc_id, count(things.*) as count").group("locations.id").order("count(things.*)")
  end
end
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?